# chrome extension - how to use window.tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get tab id from created window.
From what I saw on the developer site, the 'window' variable has a 'tabs' property that is an array of 'Tab'.
But I could not use it in any way.
What is the right way to do it?

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function (window) {
  tabid=window.tabs[0].tab.id;
  url=window.tabs[0].tab.pendingUrl;
  console.log(tabid + " " + url);
})
```

Comment: Remove  `.tab` from both lines.

Comment: @wOxxOm I get an error "Cannot read property '0'" and if I remove [0] I get an error "Cannot read property 'id'"

Comment: 1) Use devtools to set a breakpoint and inspect the values. You can also do a console.log for the `window`. 2) It's possible that onCreated event doesn't populate `tabs` so you'll need to use chrome.windows.get(window.id, {populate: true}, wnd => { ....... })